# The right form to work with pages

Tags: theming, 8, workflows

Reciently, I'm starting to work with Drupal 8, but I have some problems working with main pages. I can create a content type for all pages, but, the fields I use in to create this, must be content all posible options to input in all pages, and, for the final user, this solution can be a little confusing.

For instance, in one page I need to create a field to related another content type, with unlimited inputs, to display in this page. But, in another page, I need another related content type, with only one input.

The same case happenend for static blocks or similar.

Of course, I can create a content type for each diferent pages, but sounds like a horrible solution (I think).

I Acquainted with the suggestion template system, and I use it, but not satisfy this casuistic.

Perhaps, I'm totally wrong with the workflow of drupal and the solution is work totally diferent.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create a content type for each different page. You need some tools for site building. I think in your case [Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) will be the best solution.

You can for example create different paragraph types with a reference field, one to a content type with one input and one to another content type with unlimited inputs. You can define as many paragraphs types as you want.

Then you put a paragraph field in the page content type and the user can fill this field with the paragraphs he needs to build the content, so that each page can have a different layout.